# Fastest way to switch to a buffer in Vim?

Tags: vimrc, buffers

One way to select a buffer in Vim could be to browse the buffers list, using standard commands as `:ls`, or with [some external plugin / vimscript code to browse a list in a window](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/how-do-i-have-buffers-listed-in-a-quickfix-window-in-vim).

Let's say I want to jump to a buffer directly, as fast as possible.

To traverse the buffer list in sequential mode, I now use `<C-J>` `<C-K>` shortcuts, having set in my .vimrc:

```
" move among buffers with CTRL
map <C-J> :bnext<CR>
map <C-K> :bprev<CR>
```

Another way (direct access) could be [switching by number](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching#Switching_by_number): knowing the buffer number, it is possible to switch directly by entering the buffer number followed by `<C-^>`. So if I want to switch to buffer number 5, I would press `5<C-^>`.

But this seem not working for me (I use vim 7.4 on ubuntu box, from a Windows guest, with *Italian keyboard*). I suspect that's because the `^` character is in the upper case key `^ì` in the Italian keyboard, so in fact to got `^` I need to press `SHIFT-^`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you press `<c-6>` instead of `<c-^>`?

Comment: do you mean Ctrl-1 to go to buffer number 1 ? Unfortunately doesn't work. nothing happen

Comment: No. Some terminals can understand Ctrl-6 which is the same as Ctrl-^ on the US keyboard.

Comment: +1 Great, It work! I use an Italian keyboard layout (using putty terminal emulator). So: `1<C-6>` switchs to buffer number 1. Thanks!

Comment: You can try to use [CtrlSpace](https://github.com/vim-ctrlspace/vim-ctrlspace).

Comment: You can also open any alternative buffer in a new window by typing: `Ctrl-w 5 Ctrl-6` where 5 is the alternative buffer you want to open and also `Ctrl-w Ctrl-6`.

Comment: I learned quite a lot from just reading your question. Thanks

Answer (score 95):

The `:b` command can also take a *substring* of the name of the file of the buffer which you want to travel to, which is very convenient.

For example, if you have three buffers `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, then

- `:b bar` will switch to the `bar` file.
- `:b o` will switch to the `foo` file.
- `:b a` will give you an error because it could mean either `bar` or `baz`, but you can fix the name to be more specific with, for example, <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This can be very useful, because it means instead of

```
:buffer very/very/long/path/to/a/veryVeryLongFileName.txt
```

you can do something like

```
:b LongFileName
```

which is much shorter and easier.

This command can also take a number, if you want to use that:

```
:b 5
```

Comment: A caveat about using partial buffer names: if the partial buffer name appears at the beginning of a word boundary in some buffer's path, no buffer with the partial name in the middle of a word will be accessible by the `:b` command. For example, if you have two buffers `path/to/foo` and `path/to/tofu`, the command `:b f<Tab>` will never match `path/to/tofu`, since it matches at the beginning of a word in `path/to/foo`.

Comment: `:5b` is slightly shorter then `:b 5`  ;-)

Comment: @joeytwiddle or `:b5` if one prefers:)

Answer (score 42):

This is what I use:

```
nnoremap <Leader>b :ls<CR>:b<Space>
```

Now pressing `\b` will **list the available buffers** and prepare `:b` for you.

Then you can just type the **buffer number**, and hit Enter.

Or you can type **part of the filename**, and hit Enter.  (However I usually hit Tab before hitting Enter, to check I got the right buffer.  If not, I continue cycling with Tab until I get the one I wanted.)

---

In fact, I use a slightly tweaked version of the above:

```
nnoremap <C-e> :set nomore <Bar> :ls <Bar> :set more <CR>:b<Space>
```

This will prevent the `-- More --` prompt from appearing when you have more buffers than available lines to display them.

But if you usually have the `'more'` option disabled anyway, this mapping will really annoy you, because it re-enables the `'more'` option after doing `ls`!

Comment: Truth be told, I don't actually use either of those, I use [my own little plugin](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.vim/plugin/joeys_buffer_switcher.vim), but the functionality is very similar.  With the plugin, I can also perform Tab-complete on the filenames of un-opened buffers.

Comment: Although this technique isn't as fast as using `[count]<C-^>` when you know the buffer number, it is pretty useful when you don't know.

Comment: thanks joeytwiddle for your notes. I'll check your plugin asap. In my case (see keyboard issue above) `[count]<C-6>` appear to me the fastest way to switch to known buffer

Comment: Yeah I am also using `[count]<C-^>` these days. But that means I need to run MiniBufExplorer or something similar, to know what the buffer numbers are!

Comment: why do you need the <CR> and the <SPACE>? At first it appears to me, as if it works fine without them...

Comment: @Felix.C The `<CR>` is to run the `ls` command, so we can see what buffers are available. The `<Space>` is not needed if you are typing a number, but it is useful if you want to type `[part_of_filename]<Tab>`.

Comment: I like to use the airline plugin to show all buffers with their numbers on top (like a tab bar) to speed this up. Install airline and set these 2: `let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1` and `let g:airline#extensions#tabline#buffer_nr_show = 1`.

Comment: @joeytwiddle Assume we use this method, is there any way to avoid pressing Enter after entering the buffer number?

Answer (score 24):

### `:CtrlPBuffer` from plugin [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) (5k ★)

Main feature of this plugin is to provide a *fuzzy matching* to conveniently open a different buffer with visual feedback.

Open the fuzzy buffer listing with `:CtrlPBuffer` or press `<C-p>` followed by `<C-b>` to change the mode to `buffer`.

Enter a sufficient number of characters to specify the buffer you want to open.
You can also use `<C-j>` and `<C-k>` to cycle through the list and select manually the buffer.

[image]

#### Customization

If you wish to open the buffer list immediately with `<C-p>`, add following line to your vimrc:

```
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlPBuffer'
```

You can use `<C-f/b>` to switch the mode of the ctrlp window.

I personally use `let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlPMRU'`. The most recently used (mru) list  also contains the opened buffers. If you use different ctrlp modes and want to stick to your last mode, you can set `let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlPLastMode [--dir]'`.

#### Similar plugins

There are many more plugins which provide a buffer list with an interactive prompt with fuzzy matching, e.g.

- [**fzf.vim**](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) (8.5k ★) by Junegunn (+terminal, go)
- [**telescope.nvim**](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) (8k ★) by TJ DeVries  (for neovim)
- [**command-t**](https://github.com/wincent/command-t) by Wincent (+ruby)

#### The dark side vs. the light side

(i.e. plugin-heavy vim setup vs. the vim way)

Before you decide to use these more complex plugins, study the answers by [@Doorknob](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2131/1292) and [@joeytwiddle](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2187/1292). In particular, check the one-liner if one of them already fulfills your needs.

1. `nnoremap <Leader>b :b <C-d>`
2. `nnoremap <Leader>b :ls<Cr>:b<Space>`

Installing the plugins just for buffer switching might be an overkill.
See also the remarks on [https://www.vi-improved.org/recommendations](https://www.vi-improved.org/recommendations/#bufexplorer-ctrl-p-gtfo-minibufexpl-nerdtree-vinegar) and the article by Drew Neil [‘On sharpening the saw’](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2012/08/on-sharpening-the-saw/).

Comment: yes Hotschke, I confess i often use :CtrlPBuffer

Comment: I am using ``map <leader>a <ESC>:CtrlPBuffer<CR><CR>`` to jump to the previously opened buffer with ``<leader>a`` (while ``<leader>b`` just opens the buffer list for me)

Comment: @Rolf: do you know `<C-^>` (= `<C-6>`)? see `:h CTRL-^`.  Afaik, this just does what your mapping `<leader>a` seems to do. Therefore I think you just brought an example why people say using plugins might lead to vim user who do not know what vim already can do on its own.

Comment: @Hotschke: No, I didn't know that. Learned something knew, thanks! I'm gonna remap <C-^> though.

Comment: Excellent reference to <C-d> with vanilla vim.  I haven't seen that reference anywhere else.

Answer (score 14):

### `[b` and `]b` from plugin [`vim-unimpaired`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) (> 3k ★)

If you happen to have installed `vim-unimpaired`, you can use

- **`[b` (`:bp[revious]`)** and
- **`]b` (`:bn[ext]`)**

for cycling through open buffers. No need to define more precious mappings for the same commands. Furthermore, jumping to the first and last buffer can be done by

- `[B` (`:bf[irst]`) and
- `]B` (`:bl[ast]`).

There are [plenty more bracket-mappings](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/master/doc/unimpaired.txt#L18-L41) contained in `vim-unimpaired` which you might find useful. They all follow the same scheme which makes it easy to memorize them.

#### The dark side vs. the light side

This plugin can be considered lightweight and 'vimish'. It is denoted by the [#vim community](https://www.vi-improved.org/plugins/) as a "does not harm" plugin.

Comment: +1 Also worth noting that you can provide a count. `3[b` to jump three buffers back.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to really useful answers by joeytwiddle and Doorknob don't forget about `:b#`, which switches to most recently used buffer. It can also be done with just `<C-^>`. When you have a lot of buffers and you constantly switch between them, the most recent buffer is usually the most common destination.

Personally I use combination of many methods. When I'm working with mainly two buffers and the rest is opened just for occasional reference, I tend to switch between them with `:b#` or `<C-^>`. When I have to work with more of them and switch more often, I use either numbers (as in joeytwiddle tip), or part of names (as in Doorknob tip) with TAB to complete them. When the names are confusing, and there are many buffers opened (usually over 10), I use Ctrl-P plugin more often (https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) With two fast keystrokes I got the list of them all and I'm able to use powerful fuzzy search over them to find quickly what I want.

Comment: <C-^> alone (<C-6> in my case, as  Peter Rincker suggested) is a good trick in case of just 2 buffers :-)

Answer (score 4):

Currently I'm using `<Leader>`+`number` key to switch. The leader key is my `<space>` key.
I also use [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) to show the buffer nr on top of the window.

```
" airline settings
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#buffer_nr_show = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
```

While the bufnr often exceeds 10, so I tweak my own mapping, if the `number` is the only match, switch buffer immediately, otherwise wait for more number input or `<space>` key for confirm:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>1 tweak#wtb_switch#key_leader_bufnum(1)
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>2 tweak#wtb_switch#key_leader_bufnum(2)
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>3 tweak#wtb_switch#key_leader_bufnum(3)
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>4 tweak#wtb_switch#key_leader_bufnum(4)
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>5 tweak#wtb_switch#key_leader_bufnum(5)
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>6 tweak#wtb_switch#key_leader_bufnum(6)
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>7 tweak#wtb_switch#key_leader_bufnum(7)
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>8 tweak#wtb_switch#key_leader_bufnum(8)
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>9 tweak#wtb_switch#key_leader_bufnum(9)




func! tweak#wtb_switch#key_leader_bufnum(num)
    let l:buffers = tweak#wtb_switch#buflisted()
    let l:input = a:num . ""

    while 1

        let l:cnt = 0
        let l:i=0
        " count matches
        while l:i<len(l:buffers)
            let l:bn = l:buffers[l:i] . ""
            if l:input==l:bn[0:len(l:input)-1]
                let l:cnt+=1
            endif
            let l:i+=1
        endwhile

        " no matches
        if l:cnt==0 && len(l:input)>0
            echo "no buffer [" . l:input . "]"
            return ''
        elseif l:cnt==1
            return ":b " . l:input . "\<CR>"
        endif

        echo ":b " . l:input

        let l:n = getchar()

        if l:n==char2nr("\<BS>") ||  l:n==char2nr("\<C-h>")
            " delete one word
            if len(l:input)>=2
                let l:input = l:input[0:len(l:input)-2]
            else
                let l:input = ""
            endif
        elseif l:n==char2nr("\<CR>") || (l:n<char2nr('0') || l:n>char2nr('9'))
            return ":b " . l:input . "\<CR>"
        else
            let l:input = l:input . nr2char(l:n)
        endif

        let g:n = l:n

    endwhile
endfunc

func! tweak#wtb_switch#buflisted()
  return filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')
endfunc
```

The code is pasted from [here](https://github.com/roxma/vim-tweak/commit/53e8e54748ab22e3b93617d3122facde77616120)

By the way, I also use `<S-h>` and `<S-l>` for `:bp` and `:bn`, or `:tabp` and `:tabn` if more than one tabpage is opened currently. It's quite intuitive for me.

Comment: yesssssss. glad i scrolled down on this thread. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

These days I am using `[buffer_number]<Ctrl-^>` to switch buffers because it is very fast.

But how to know the buffer number?  I use [MiniBufExplorer](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim) so I can always see the buffer numbers at the top of Vim.

I also use the following mapping, because `<C-^>` is a bit hard to reach with one hand.

```
:nmap <C-E> <C-^>
```

---

On a fresh machine with no config, I fall back to `:b [part_of_filename]<Tab><Enter>`

Answer (score 2):

[junegunn/fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) provides `:Buffers` for fuzzy search.

```
nnoremap <Leader>b :Buffers
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do like [@joeytwiddle](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2187/1292). But also use the `nano` way to cycle through buffers, which I find pretty handy:

```
" alt + ,
nnoremap ^[, :bp<cr>
" alt + .
nnoremap ^[. :bn<cr>
```